# R group by problem_the multiple combination ID

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyr

I'm using group by function in a dataset using R software. But the target of the id would duplicate. Here is the sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c ("A","A","B","C","C","D"), 
                  Var1 = c(1,3,2,3,1,2))


ID  Var1  
A    1   
A    3  
B    2  
C    3  
C    1  
D    2
```

I've to group ID by A+B and B+C and D (PS. say that F=A+B ,G=B+C) and the target result dataset below:

```
ID  Var1   
F   6  
G   6  
D   2
```

I use the following code to solve it

```
library(dplyr)     
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(F=ifelse(ID %in% c("A", "B"), 1, 0),
              G = ifelse(ID %in% c("B", "C"), 1, 0),
              D = ifelse(ID == "D", 1, 0))

  df %>% 
  gather(var, val, F:D) %>% 
  filter(val==1) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(Var1=sum(Var1))
```

BUT this way failed because of the memory limit (the dataset is large)
Is there another way to solve it?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your sample dataset in the form of code, e.g. a `tibble` or `data.frame` definition.  Also, you have `Var1` in your sample dataset, but then `V1` in later references.  If `Var1 == V1`, edit your post to make naming consistent.

Comment: Sample dataset code provided and also Var1 == V1,Thanks! @andrew_reece

Comment: This is a pretty fast operation, the dataset you've provided completes in about 0.007 seconds on my machine.  What are the dimensions of the full dataset you are operating on?

Comment: The original data set dimensions are 2463406 *5  , and the new group ID has 40 combinations. So that after I mutate my data set, it has 2463406*47 dimension. Current Code would failed on the "gather" step,where the dimension would expand up to 103463052*7. That's why I search another solution, Thanks! @andrew_reece